# RecyclerView - wait for views to be ready

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I start my activity, I want to show my tutorials, therefore I need to wait for the `RecyclerView` to be ready, in my use case, I want the first 4 items to be ready. I tried following:

```
GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this, Tools.isScreenLandscape(this) ? 3 : 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
{
    boolean mTutorialHandled = false;

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(final RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, final RecyclerView.State state)
    {
        super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
        // make sure, at least the first 4 views are ready
        if (!mTutorialHandled)
        {
            boolean allViewsReady = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                allViewsReady &= recycler.getViewForPosition(i) != null;
            if (allViewsReady)
            {
                TutorialManager.checkTutorial(false, savedInstanceState, MainActivity.this, mBinding);
                mTutorialHandled = true;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

But this is not working. Anyone knows how to know when first n views of the `RecyclerView` are ready?

Comment: what do you mean by `wait for views to be ready` ? that `onBindViewHolder` was called with the position [0.. n -1]?

Comment: Exactly. I need the views to be layed out so that I can use the views so that my tutorial overlays can correctly mark them

Comment: so do some checks inside `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: I've done that already once and it's working, now I'm using a library for my `RecyclerView` items that is quite decoupled from the `RecyclerView` and am looking for a way via the `RecylcerView` or `LayoutManager`. at least the second should know when it lays out which view. Going the route through the `ViewHolders` is working, but in my case this means I must subclass the `RecyclerView` so that my `ViewHolders` can notify the `RecyclerView` and then I can add a custom listener to my sub classes `RecyclerView`. I just want to know if there's a more generic approach for this...

Comment: you must subclass `RecyclerView.Adapter`, not `RecyclerView`

Comment: Both works... I now had an idea, counting the `onGlobalLayout` of the `RecyclerView` seems promising, but I must check that... Seems like it's called for every item in the `RecyclerView`...

Comment: Tried it and it's not reliable, I'll use the way through the `ViewHolder` and it's `bindView` call, that's working reliable...

Comment: `ViewHolder` does not have `bindView` method

Comment: In my case it does as well, but you're right. But my solution is quite simple and is working directly via the Adapter, just as you suggested

Comment: Thanks for your feedbackk though